# how to make scatter plot with halo effect using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a latent space of Gaussian random variables
where `x_i~Gaussian(u_i, simga_i)`
I want to represent uncertainty in the plot like this picture
[image: plot made by someone]
But I can't find any API of how to do this with Matplotlib!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like the example below? (modified from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_transparency_blend.html))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def normal_pdf(x, mean, var):
    return np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2*var))

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = (0, 100, 0, 100)

N = 1000
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, N)
yy = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, N)

x = normal_pdf(xx, 50, 75)
y = normal_pdf(yy, 50, 75)

weights = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y)).prod(0)

plt.imshow(weights, extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(50, 50, "bo")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The plot you made is what I wanted, but I wonder how to extend this plot to much more general scatter plot? Case I have a large latent space with many points to be plotted

Comment: For multiple points you could create a function `add_point` that takes the current `axes` as an argument, and plot with `ax.imshow`. The linked example does this for 2 points. If you're concerned with the number of point to be plotted (for instance if your output is a .pdf), you could consider [rasterising](https://matplotlib.org/examples/misc/rasterization_demo.html) your plot.

Answer (score 0):

To add more points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def normal_pdf(x, mean, var):
    return np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2*var))

def add_point(mu, std, ax):
    x = normal_pdf(xx, mu, std)
    y = normal_pdf(yy, xmax-mu, std)
    weights = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y)).prod(0)
    ax.imshow(weights, extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.5)
    plt.plot(mu, mu, "bo")


xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = (0, 150, 0, 150)

N = 1000
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, N)
yy = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, N)

fig, _ax = plt.subplots()

add_point(50, 75, _ax)
add_point(10, 25, _ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```